# the PAA (piecewise aggregate approximation) algorithm

Tags: python

I'm working on dimensionality reduction of time series and I want to calculate the PAA (piecewise aggregate approximation) algorithm in python to reduce the lengths of the time series. I need help.

I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [`tslearn.piecewise.PiecewiseAggregateApproximation`](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gen_modules/piecewise/tslearn.piecewise.PiecewiseAggregateApproximation.html):

Here's an example:

```py
from tslearn.piecewise import PiecewiseAggregateApproximation
import numpy as np

# Sample time series data, shape = (n_samples, n_timestamps, n_features)
X = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]).reshape((1, -1, 1))

# Initialize PAA transformer with desired output size
paa = PiecewiseAggregateApproximation(n_segments=5)

# Fit and transform data
X_paa = paa.fit_transform(X)

print("Original:", X[0, :, 0])
print("Reduced:", X_paa[0, :, 0])
```

**Output showing the original series is now approximated into five segments:**

```
Original: [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
Reduced: [ 1.5  3.5  5.5  7.5  9.5]
```

Comment: On what basis did you choose the number of segments equal to 5, is there a specific rule?

Comment: 10/2 = 5 just as an example